# Resource views in Django

Tags: python, django, rest, oop, django-views

I'm using Django for the first time (I'm also new to Python in general) and I've been struggling with a certain problem related to class based views for a while now. I'm coming from PHP with Laravel, where you can have so-called "RESTful Resource Controllers".

For everyone not familiar with Laravel: the idea is that you have one controller (or view, in Django-speak) per 'resource'. This controller/view defines methods such as `index()`, `show()`, `create()`, `store()`, `edit()`, etc. The associated urls and HTTP methods for these controller methods are `GET /photos`, `GET /photos/1`, `GET /photos/create`, `POST /photos`, `GET /photos/1/edit` respectively (for example, if you're dealing with photos). In Laravel's routing, you have to declare just one line `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')` and those URLs are automatically generated. For more info, I refer to [Laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers).

I really like this pattern and I'd like to use it in Django.

As far as I understand, Django doesn't really have such a thing out of the box. Django does have class based views, but those don't represent resources. Rather, you have a view for your 'index()' (`PhotoListView`), a view for your 'show()' (`PhotoDetailView`) and so on.

I'm not sure how I should implement this pattern in Django, and I'm not even sure if what I want is a good idea.

After researching I found some info that might be of use:

http://watchitlater.com/blog/2010/02/django-restful-resources/
https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/put-and-delete-http-requests-with-django-and-jquery/

I'm not sure what the custom View class from the first link accomplishes that the stock Django View can't (a normal Django View does more or less the same thing, right?), and I don't think the second link does exactly what I want (if I understand correctly, the article merely describes a middleware as a solution for the problem that Django doesn't put data sent with a DELETE/PUT request in a request).

Based on this, I devised two potential solutions:

- Use a single line in the URLconf that matches all URLs for a certain resource, like this:

  `url(r'^photos/(.*)$', PhotoView.as_view())`

  The `as_view()` function of the custom View base class would then handle the routing of the URLs like `/photos`, `/photos/1` and `/photos/1/edit` and so on to the correct class methods. The disadvantage is that you put routing in a view (not the correct place to do that) and that you can't use named patterns this way to refer to the URLs elsewhere in your code. It is closest to the way its works in Laravel though.
- Use separate lines in the URLconf for each URL, like:

  `url(r'^photos$', PhotoView.index)
  url(r'^photos/(\d+)$', PhotoView.show)
  url(r'^photos/(\d+)/edit$', PhotoView.edit)`

  The benefit of this is that named patterns work as usual, and all the routing stays in the URLconf. However, I don't know how to accomplish this in terms of implementation of the View class (I'd have to decorate every method @classonlymethod, right).

Sorry for the wall of text, I'd gladly hear your thoughts on how to best solve this. Or maybe I'm just batshit crazy and should I just use function based views like every normal Django coder?

Comment: Have you seen the [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)?

Comment: @JensAstrup Yes, I've (repeatedly) stumbled upon that. I'm not building an API though, but a website/webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom class based view that is more or less a mix of the two proposed solutions in the question.

The general idea is that I have a `ResourceView` that follows the same structure as Django's `View` class (it has `as_view()` and `dispatch()` methods). Just like Django's `View`, `as_view()` defines a closure inside that is returned to the URLconf. This closure in turn relies on `dispatch()` to dispatch the request to the correct (child) method. For this, it uses a '2d map' (dict of dicts) to determine which method should be called for which combination of route (URL) and HTTP method. The difference with Django's `View` is that `as_view()` is called in the URLconf with a parameter that specifies the route.

I also have a `ResourceRouter` that automatically generates the URLconf corresponding to the view. This approach is somewhat inspired by how DRF handles this.

Last but not least I wrote a decorator that 'binds' the model instance to the method, so instead of the pk the model instance is passed to the view method.

The code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Compizfox/c4e3044755417f59dc33ce97ac8ca07c

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4974980/jens-astrup) in the comments. The third party Django Rest Framework is the closest thing that we have to the laravel controller that you have described. The specific item to look at is [viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/).

> Django REST framework allows you to combine the logic for a set of
>   related views in a single class, called a ViewSet. In other frameworks
>   you may also find conceptually similar implementations named something
>   like 'Resources' or 'Controllers'.

DRF has a very steep learning curve. DRF also conveys the impression that it's only suited for creating an API. However, the reality is that DRF can be used to [render HTML and process ordinary HTML forms](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/).

> REST framework is suitable for returning both API style responses, and
>   regular HTML pages. Additionally, serializers can used as HTML forms
>   and rendered in templates.

The alternative of course is to use Class Based Views. The disadvantage is that it does not provide all the functionality of a DRF viewset in a single class. But all is not lost. You can make use of [CBV Mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/mixins/) to mix and match the functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks. I indeed got the impression that it was only for APIs, not for websites, which is why I hadn't looked into it more.

DRF seems to be what I'm looking for, however I've already written a custom View base class that does what I want and is much simpler than DRF (though not as flexible) and doesn't require learning a whole new framework. I'll post it as an answer when it's finished.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, however you don't need to write a view class from scratch, you can maix and match the mixins as mentioned, that way you will have to write very little code

Comment: Too late, I've already written it... ;) I'll check if I can refactor it with use of these mixins though. Thanks for the tip.